# Bacteria branching process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

The population starts with one individual. Per one period, the individual can either split into two, survive, or die, each with probability one third. What is the expected population size after n periods?

Comment: What have you tried? Also what is the probability of each possibility?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: thank you for your comment: I edited the question to specify the probability to be 1/3. I had a shot at drawing a trinomial tree and playing around with it, but didn't get to a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Define $Y_n$ the amount of individuals at step $n$, and notice that if $Y_n=m$ then you have $m$ R.V-s $X_{i}$, where each $X_i$ satisfies

$$ \mathbb{P}(X_i=1),\mathbb{P}(X_i=2),\mathbb{P}(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{3}. $$

Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{Y_n} X_i=Y_{n+1}$ and that this gives you a simple identity for $\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}\vert Y_n=m].$ Can you carry on from this point?

Comment: That's great, thanks for that!